# IIS7 URL Rewrite 403 errors

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am setting up a simple URL rewrite rule to point to an application I have setup in IIS7.

I am using the IIS 7 URL Rewrite module inside IIS7.

I setup a simple rule that I point to my web application and all I recieve are 403 errors.   I have tested a rewrite on a very simple hello world application that I created in IIS and it works fine.

Is there something in my application's web.config or in IIS that needs to grant permission URL rewrites ?